# Swift MPGTextField autocomplete in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't see suggestions when typing.. i have tableview cell and textfield in it.

I'm using [MPGTextField](https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField) library, [swift version](https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField/issues/22#issuecomment-154628946)(swift 2 supported).

Any solution for this?

[image]

Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var articleField: MPGTextField_Swift!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    articleField.mDelegate = self
}

func dataForPopoverInTextField(textfield: MPGTextField_Swift) -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
    return articles
}

func textFieldShouldSelect(textField: MPGTextField_Swift) -> Bool{
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: MPGTextField_Swift, withSelection data: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>){
    print(data["CustomObject"])
}
```

Comment: Can you give so more details? Some code? What have you tired?

Comment: I used their example, and everything works, but when i put textfield in tableview cell then i get this break, can't see suggestions. I need to make suggestions in front.  Updated question with code..

Comment: Where is the dictionary being stored? Where is the data being parsed/queried from? Maybe you're having an issue with querying the data (which is most likely). Are you using Core Data or a server to display the data you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `MPGTextField-Swift.swift` you'll find a function `provideSuggestions()`
In this function you'll find a line

```
self.superview!.addSubview(tableViewController!.tableView)
```

Replace this line with

```
//BUG FIX - SHOW ON TOP

//self.superview!.addSubview(tableViewController!.tableView)

let aView = tableViewController!.tableView
var frame = aView.frame

frame.origin = self.superview!.convertPoint(frame.origin, toView: nil)
aView.frame = frame

self.window!.addSubview(aView)

////
```

I've forked `MPGTextField` repository, made necessary changes for demo purpose.
You can find my repo at https://github.com/rishi420/MPGTextField

**Note**: This repo needs Xcode 7.1.1 to compile. Feel free to contribute. :-]

Comment: Thanks, there is one more bug i found, when 3 results shows, and you click on second or third, it always select first.

Comment: did you understand me, when you click on any of suggestions, it always select first element.

Comment: yes. pull the repo. run the project. same bug? not the original repository. download this one https://github.com/rishi420/MPGTextField

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell what's going on. Is the autocomplete box showing but just cut off at the bottom of the `tableViewCell`? If so, try setting `clipsToBounds` to false on the `tableViewCell`, and maybe even its content view too.

Touch events are not by default recognized for areas outside of a view's frame. To route the taps to the suggestion, you'll have to subclass the `tableViewCell` and override `hitTest`

Comment: Now it shows suggestions, but i can't click on them.. that is tableview suggestions, and i can't click on any suggestion. How to fix this?

Comment: Image: http://s23.postimg.org/oc6d3bc63/Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_17_2015_01_15_06.png

Comment: You can also try enabling touch on those cells.

Comment: Tap works only on that cell, but when i tap on results that are in other cells, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this would be set the cell height when the cell is selected:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath {
        return self.selectedCellHeight
    }

    return self.unSelectedCellHeight
}
```

You only have to set the `unselectedCellHeight` and the `selectedCellHeight`

The `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` will update the cell height and **animate** it.